# Drawing 6 balls of different colours

Tags: probability

Hi I have an exam on Monday and am doing a few probability questions. I have checked the mark scheme for the answer to the following question however the method isn't stated.

Could someone please help me?

The question is as follows:

> How many ways can 6 balls be drawn from 49 balls out of which 16 are blue, 16 are red and 17 are green if balls of the same colour are not distinguishable?

Thank you so much

Comment: the answer given is 8C2

Comment: Please see Wikipedia, Stars and Bars. The number of balls of each colour is irrelevant, as long as there are at least $6$ of each.

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you show any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the working I've tried is I've tried to use combinatiions such as "(16C6)(16C6)(17C6)" this is not right of course as it would require 6 balls to be chosen 3 times. I know that the 6 balls are chosen out of 49 balls in total so maybe I have to use (49C6) somewhere in my workings?

Comment: In future, please include your attempt in the statement of the question.  You are more likely to obtain a response if you show your work and indicate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1$ denote the number of blue balls that are selected; let $x_2$ denote the number of red balls that are selected; let $x_3$ denote the number of green balls that are selected.  Then the number of ways of drawing six balls from the $16$ blue balls, $16$ red balls, and $17$ green balls is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_1 \leq 16$, $x_2 \leq 16$, and $x_3 \leq 17$.  Since there are at least six balls of each color, we do not need to worry about the restrictions (if there were fewer than six balls of one or more of the colors, we would have to use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle).

A particular solution of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6$ in the nonnegative integers corresponds to a choice of where to place two addition signs in a row of six ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 1 + + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the selection of three blue balls, no red balls, and three green balls, while 
$$1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1$$
corresponds to the selection of one blue ball, three red balls, and two green balls.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can select two of the eight symbols (the six ones and two addition signs) to be addition signs, which is $\binom{8}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you, just to check I understand, if we had to choose 10 balls instead of 6, would the answer be 12C2? As there are still two addition symbols?

Comment: That is correct.  The same method would work for up to $16$ balls.  Beyond that, you would have to use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your answer and in future I will write my attempts when posting a question